# Orchard Core - InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' not found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms-1.6

I'm working on an Orchard Core 1.6.0 solution where I've added two modules: a theme and a "History" module.
[image: Navigation Layout]

The theme, as best I can tell, works fine. It even fetches the Layout.liquid without issue. The History module, on the other hand, gives me this:
[image: InvalidOperationException]

It does this regardless of whether or not I "return View()" as "Index", "./Views/Home/Index.cshtml" or "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"

My startup.cs looks like this:
[image: Startup cs]

Can anyone provide some clues as to what is going on here? I've scoured the All-Knowing 'Net and tried what solutions I could but nothing seems to work. Any and all clues greatly appreciated.

Comment: I once met a similar issue although my controllers and views are ok.What I tried to fix it: 
 Open the solution in another visual studio,clean the solution and rebuild

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't really work for me. Even more frustrating, I decided to recreate my project from scratch. I tested that and, to my surprise, it actually worked but I have no idea what I did different from my original project. Adding to the madness, when I do the exact same steps that created the working project, that new project doesn't work. And, if I take the project that works and copy it to a new directory, that project fails in the same way as the others. This is just nuts.